# UI-Router nested view not working

Tags: angularjs, nested, state, angular-ui-router, breadcrumbs

I am trying to create nested view with angular breadcrumb ... and here the problem is in state **app.input1.input2** its own template **input2** is not loading.. its only loading **app.input1** continuously...

If I try to give wrong templateUrl in **app.input1.input2** then it throws error back but when I give correct path then its not loading same template and any error .. it just loading same template of **app.input1**

Suggest me some idea why that template is not loading?

**#app.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/app',
        templateUrl: 'view/abc.html',
        data: {
        breadcrumbProxy: 'app.start'
        }
    })

    .state('app.start', {
        url: '/start',
        templateUrl: 'view/start.html',
        data: {
            displayName: 'start',
          }
    })        

    .state('app.input1', {
        url: '/input1',
        templateUrl: 'view/input1.html',
          data: {
            displayName: 'input1',
          }
    })

    .state('app.input1.input2', {
        url: '/input2',    
        templateUrl: 'view/input2',
          data: {
            displayName: 'input2',
          }
    });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app.start');
```

**index.html**

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

**abc.html**

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

**start.html**

```
<div>
    <a ui-sref="app.input1">Input1</a>
</div>
```

**input1.html**

```
<div>
    <a ui-sref="app.input1.input2">Input2</a>
</div>
```

**input2.html**

```
<div>bla bla bla bla</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OdUDblERlWaXeeosVDej?p=preview). Change made is here:

**input1.html**

```
<div>
    <a ui-sref="app.input1.input2">Input2</a>
    <div ui-view></div> // anchor for child
</div>
```

The `input2` is a child state of `input1`. So we need to create an anchor/target for it. Check the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OdUDblERlWaXeeosVDej?p=preview)

Also, I used this as otherwise:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/start');
```

Comment: thankyou for you plnkr.. but still one more question... here's my plnkr.. http://plnkr.co/edit/EGhFEVgMKHsa9c5ZapOQ?p=preview .. actually i wanna ve those breadcrumb same as input1/input2 .. and i want to show only input2 template below... i dont want input2 tag in that view.... how can i remove that??

Comment: Here you are: http://plnkr.co/edit/EGhFEVgMKHsa9c5ZapOQ?p=preview. Change is only script.js and the input2 def. If you want to understand what happend, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25678843/1679310) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25349647/1679310) ... ;) Good luck with the `UI-Router`

Comment: Ooops. http://plnkr.co/edit/CQNjsRyyMaD8s1D0NT9L?p=preview this is the proper link to updated plunker. Reaaaaally sorry. wrong copy paste. Really sorry ;(