# Angular UI router nested views when targeting parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Given this snippet

```
$stateProvider
    .state('authorized', {
        abstract: true, 
        template: "<div ui-view='page'>hello</div>"
    })
    .state('task', {
      parent: 'authorized',
      abstract: true,
      url: '/task',
    })
    .state('task.create', {
      url: '/create',
      'views': {
        'page@authorized': {
          template: "word<div ui-view='boom'>replaced</div>",
          views: {
            'boom': {
              template: "up"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

I was expecting to see "word up", instead I see "word replaced" - I think I'm misunderstanding how angular ui targets parent states, help appreciated.

Demo plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/69kdcy?p=preview

Comment: Were you looking for this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZjAantupsA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated that [plunker with this change](http://plnkr.co/edit/xTT6H6?p=preview):

```
    .state('task.create', {
      url: '/create',
      'views': {
          'page@authorized': {
             template: "word<div ui-view='boom'>replaced</div>",
          },
          'boom@task.create': {
              template: "up"
          }
        }
    })
```

So, what is different? The **`views`** definition is on the same level. Because we want to inject boom into current state template, we have to append its name at the end **`'boom@task.create'`**

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xTT6H6?p=preview)

*If you do not mind, check this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25349647/1679310) to see how I try to use nesting for standard layout*

Comment: Great sir, Enjoy UI-Router ;)